# create service-endpoint in Kilt DID

Tags: polkadot-js, extrinsic, kilt, did

I would like to add a service-endpoint to my Kilt DID, using the Javascript SDK.

I have created a full DID and am trying to add the service-endpoint like so:

```js
const extrinsic = api.createType('Extrinsic', { id: `#${id}`, type: [type], serviceEndpoint: [url] });

const authorizedTx = await Did.authorizeTx(
    didUri,
    extrinsic,
    signRequest(didUri, didAuth),
    submitterAccount.address
);
```

the `extrinsic` is not correct as I get an error

```
SDKError: No key relationship found for extrinsic
```

I was not able to find this specific actin in the Kilt documentation, so I'm asking here.

Answer (score 3):

The KILT SDK provides a very thin level of abstraction over the `api` object that the Polkadot SDK provides.

Adding a service endpoint to a KILT DID can be done in the following way:

```js
const addServiceTx = await api.tx.did.addServiceEndpoint(
  Kilt.Did.serviceToChain({
    id: `#${id}`,
    type: [type],
    serviceEndpoint: [url],
  })
)
const authorizedTx = await Did.authorizeTx(
  didUri,
  addServiceTx,
  signRequest(didUri, didAuth),
  submitterAccount.address
);
```

Comment: thank you, that worked like a charm